# Solving $x\sin(\frac 1x)$ via limit definition

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I'm trying to show that the derivative of $x\sin(\frac 1x)$ exists and is equal to $\sin(\frac 1x)-\frac {\cos(\frac 1x)}x$ for every point in its domain via the *limit definition* (I can of course just use the product and chain rules, but I want to solve it via the definition).

So I have the limit: $$\lim_{x\to c} \frac {x\sin(\frac 1x) - c\sin(\frac 1c)}{x-c}$$

Here's what I've got so far:

I know I need to get that $x-c$ to cancel on bottom and that I need a $\sin(\frac 1x)$ or $\sin(\frac 1c)$ (either will evaluate to $\sin(\frac 1c)$ after I apply the limit) in my answer so I added $c\sin(\frac 1x)-c\sin(\frac 1x)$ to the numerator.  Then I get:

$$\lim_{x\to c} \frac {(x-c)\sin(\frac 1x)+c(\sin(\frac 1x)-\sin(\frac 1c))}{x-c}$$ $$= \lim_{x\to c} \left[\sin(\frac 1x)+c\frac {\sin(\frac 1x)-\sin(\frac 1c)}{x-c}\right]$$

So I see that that second term should evaluate to $-\frac{\cos(\frac 1c)}c$, but I can't see how to get there algebraically.

I asked an upper-division friend of mine and he recommended that I try to use a subsequential limit, but I thought that only applied when $x\to \infty$.

Is this algebraic way the best way to do this problem?  And if so, what's the next step?  If not, should I be trying to find a subsequential limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: use
$$\sin x - \sin y=2\cos\left(\frac{x+y}2\right)\sin\left(\frac{x-y}2\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Note that $x-c=-xc\left(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{c}\right)$.